# Excel Macro Request: Save As Copy and Break Data Connection

Tags: vba, excel

I have a MASTER excel spreadsheet used as a template so I could refresh a CONNECTION ( .csv file) with a new data table that links to my pivot table.

Right now I have a macro to SAVE AS COPY to a specific path, since I want to keep the original intact.

```
Sub SaveCopyPath()

With ActiveWorkbook
   .SaveCopyAs "C:\Users\Me\" & Format(Date, "mmddyyyy") & "-" & [A1] & ".xlsm"
End With

End Sub
```

- I'm looking for a VBA Code that would apply only to my SAVED AS COPY with these:

  1. BREAK the connection on the data table
  2. Delete TAB1 and TAB2 on the saved copy only and keep the Pivot Table & "Data" intact on the **saved copy.**

Comment: I see you edited the question to add the fact that the source is a csv. I can modify my answer below if you give a little more guidance. Is the connection in a sructured table? Or just in a sheet?

Comment: The data pulls from CSVs and is added to a Data Model, viewed as a Table on my "Data" sheet.  I was able to get this to work by using ActiveWorkbook.Connections ("ModelConnection").Delete

Comment: Cool! That's what I was hoping would work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This uses the `ListObject.Unlink` method to delete the data connection. The rest should be straightforward:

```
Sub SaveCopyPath()
Dim SavedCopy As Excel.Workbook

ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs "C:\Users\Me\" & Format(Date, "mmddyyyy") & "-" & [A1] & ".xlsm"
Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\Me\" & Format(Date, "mmddyyyy") & "-" & [A1] & ".xlsm"
Set SavedCopy = ActiveWorkbook
With SavedCopy
    .Worksheets("Data").ListObjects(1).Unlink
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    .Worksheets(1).Delete
    .Worksheets(1).Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    .Close True
End With

End Sub
```